# Audex ripper codecs and FreeDB database access

Tags: 16.04, codecs, cd-ripping

I'd rather know how to download the codecs (mp3 flac etc etc) for Audex (ripper), is there a way to get them using the terminal? I have tried with the links available on ubuntu site but nothing happened.

Moreover on Ubuntu they say that there is also the option to access the entries of FreeDB database but all I get is the CDDB database that often does not recognise my cds. How do I add this FreeDB database option?  My version of Ubuntu is 16.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The questions really demands two answers:

**1. Install the codecs:**

The Terminal command to install a fully featured `audex` *including codecs* is as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install audex eyed3 faac flac lame twolame vorbis-tools
```

Be aware that a very large number of KDE libraries will also be dragged in as *dependencies* of `audex`, if these dependencies seem excessive to you consider installing an alternative CD ripper such as `asunder` which carries no KDE cruft...

**2. Change the CDDB database:**

This functionality is broken on Xenial Xerus (the packager has possibly missed the dependency on `kde-config-cddb`) and to fix this you will have to build the package from scratch but as a bonus you get *a newer version*!

First activate your Sources:

```
Dash > Software & Updates > Ubuntu Software > Source Code
```

Place a tick in the 'Source Code' box and then allow the Repositories to reload. Then copy the *entire* following code box into a Terminal window, it is *a single command:*

```
sudo apt-get build-dep audex && \
sudo apt-get install kdemultimedia-dev libcddb2-dev kde-config-cddb checkinstall && \
mkdir -pv ~/audex_build && cd ~/audex_build && \
wget https://github.com/KDE/audex/archive/v0.79.tar.gz && \
tar xvf v0.79.tar.gz && cd audex-0.79 && \
mkdir build && cd build && \
cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local .. && make -j 4 && \
sudo checkinstall -D --install=yes --fstrans=no --pakdir "$HOME/audex_build" \
   --pkgname audex --backup=no --deldoc=yes --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes \
   --default --pkgversion "0.79"
```

Log out and then log back in and you should now see the following:

[image: CDDB Settings for Audex]

Note that now you also have *an extra tab* called 'Device settings' to tweak your CDROM settings. And all the best with ripping your audio cds :)

Comment: Hi Andrew.46 I have finally been able to install the codecs thanks to your tip. But, since I am a bit dumb, I haven't been able to find a solution with the freedb server. I have opened the audex programme but when I open  the "configure audex" there is no  "cddb settings" and more importantly no alternative option to CDDB. In the remote server section there's the possibility to add an address "send file to server". Could it be that I have to add a freedb server address there?

Comment: @RamalamaBelle I have added a screenshot showing the required dialogue box but this does not seem readily available on Xenial Xerus. I will dig a little deeper...

Comment: from the picture I can see that I don't have the CDDB SETTINGS section. Very strange...

Comment: @RamalamaBelle Indeed this is the issue. I have created a bug report, perhaps you could also subscribe yourself to this? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/audex/+bug/1622264

Comment: @RamalamaBelle Solved the issue with CDDB, please test it out and let me know if you have any further issues :)

Comment: yes yes yes!!it worked!! you really made my day!!  :-D Thank you ^^

Comment: @RamalamaBelle And you have made my day with your happiness :). Consider upvoting this answer and even 'Accepting' it by clicking on the 'tick' or 'check' mark near my answer. This signifies to others that this is the answer that solved your problems. And have a great day :)

Comment: done :) Thank you again! Check my other question about samsung drivers  and inform me in case you find a solution :))

Comment: Is it possible to get FreeDB lookup working on 17.10?
I get the following result currently, 
code`E: Unable to find a source package for audex` which perhaps is unsurprising as audex is not in the repositories for 17.10, but even with the Xenial repositories enabled as per this answer: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011547/audex-cd-ripper-not-in-repositories] I get the same result.