# Audex CD ripper not in repositories

Tags: cd-ripping

My favourite CD ripper Audex doesn't seem to be in the repositories for 17.10. Is it available by any other means?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the audex package is available for [previous releases (as 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=Audex).

We can try to install this package from 16.04 LTS (xenial) repository.

But be carefully and do all steps as I write below:

```
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial.list

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-xenial
Package: *
Pin: release a=xenial
Pin-Priority: -1000

Package: audex
Pin: release a=xenial
Pin-Priority: 1

EOF

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kde-runtime
sudo apt-get install audex -t xenial
```

Then try to launch Audex.

And remove xenial repository and preferences file:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-xenial
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial.list
sudo apt-get update
```